# Subroutine execution repetition

Tags: programming

I like to write second and third lines repeated operation only once as a separate module with some Name. In each main program line a set of different set boundary conditions data is given,Name invoked and plots obtained. How to do such a short code? ( *Manipulate* needs constant increments).

```
    ydi=.6;yi=1.2;Omega=.77;
    NDSolve[{Y''[t]+Omega^2 Y[t]==0,Y'[0]==ydi,Y[0]==yi},Y,{t,0,Pi}];
    y[u_]=Y[u]/.First[%];Plot[{y'[t],y''[t]},{t,0,Pi},PlotLabel->  {"\[Omega],yi,ydi = ",Omeg,yi,ydi}]
    ydi=-.4;yi=1.4;Omega=-.88;
    NDSolve[{Y''[t]+Omega^2 Y[t]==0,Y'[0]==ydi,Y[0]==yi},Y,{t,0,Pi}];
    y[u_]=Y[u]/.First[%];Plot[{y'[t],y''[t]},{t,0,Pi},PlotLabel->  {"\[Omega],yi,ydi = ",Omeg,yi,ydi}]
    ydi=.12;yi=1.6;Omega=.99;
    NDSolve[{Y''[t]+Omega^2 Y[t]==0,Y'[0]==ydi,Y[0]==yi},Y,{t,0,Pi}];
    y[u_]=Y[u]/.First[%];Plot[{y'[t],y''[t]},{t,0,Pi},PlotLabel->  {"\[Omega],yi,ydi = ",Omeg,yi,ydi}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with it, but a generally good idea is to put all your parameters in list:

```
parameters = {{0.6, 1.2, .77}, {-.4, 1.4, -.88}, {.12, 1.6, .99}};
```

Now you are free to use `Table` to create a list of `NDSolve` solutions or you use `Manipulate` to plot solutions. I have kept the code close to your example so that you can see more easily how it is done.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{y, Y, Omega, ydi, yi},
  {ydi, yi, Omega} = parms;
  y[u_] = Y[u] /. First@
     NDSolve[{Y''[t] + Omega^2 Y[t] == 0, Y'[0] == ydi, Y[0] == yi}, 
      Y, {t, 0, Pi}];
  Plot[y[u], {u, 0, Pi}]
  ],
 {parms, parameters}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that with `Table` you can use the same notation `{p, parameters}` as in `Manipulate` to iterate through a list of parameters:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: What I wanted.  btw, although any label can be used, to shepherd the sets I renamed as:
superset = {{0.6, 1.2, .77}, {-.4, 1.4, -.88}, {.12, 1.6, .99}};
Manipulate[Module[{y, Y, ydi, yi, Omega}, {ydi, yi, Omega} = subset;
  y[u_] = 
   Y[u] /. First@
     NDSolve[{Y''[t] + Omega^2 Y[t] == 0, Y'[0] == ydi, Y[0] == yi}, 
      Y, {t, 0, Pi}];
  Plot[y[u], {u, 0, Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]], {subset, superset}] ; Is such sense ok?

Comment: Of course this is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, a stand-alone `Module` can be constructed.

```
f[ydi_, yi_, Omega_] := Module[{}, y[u_] = Y[u] /. 
  First@NDSolve[{Y''[t] + Omega^2 Y[t] == 0, Y'[0] == ydi, Y[0] == yi}, Y, {t, 0, Pi}];
  Plot[{y'[t], y''[t]}, {t, 0, Pi}, PlotLabel -> {"\[Omega],yi,ydi = ", Omeg, yi, ydi}]]
```

Then, for instance,

```
f[.6, 1.2, .77]
```

[image: Sample plot]

Comment: Thanks,got it. This way it does not explicitly use Manipulate.